# If the sum of dates within a week is $72$, what date is Monday?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a man who spends exactly same no. of dollars as the date (e.g. on $12$ of any month he will spend 12 dollars). In a week he spends 72 dollars. What is the amount spend by him on Monday?

I let amount spend on monday is $x$ so on next days of week he will spend $x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4,x+5,x+6$.

So $72=7x+21$. But as date on Monday should be integer I don't think I can found the solution this way. How to solve this question?

Comment: @NormalHuman suggest a title. I can't think of any title so I write this.

Comment: @DhruvaMehrotra Please note that this is from a bot, so suggestions can't be made so easily.

Comment: Note that, as the case explained, this cant be happen unless you are in a leap where february has 29   days, so the man spend  28 in 28th of February, then 29, then  1,2,3,4,5. Adding this you get that the man spends  72$ .  Indeed as you said in your post, it is imposible for 7 consecutive integres  between  1 and  31  to have sum  72. Moreover, if you take in consideration the end of each month with beginning of the following month, you will notice that this can happen just in the case of leap year  in the month of February .

Comment: @nizar I am just asking a mathematical way to solve this I don't think guessing is a mathematical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since the amount spent is assumed to be an integer, a way to resolve this is to let the person be near the end of the month. There are quite a few cases to find out, which we can prune easily with a bit of calculations.

**Upper bound:**

> Note that on the days near the end of the month, he needs to spend at least $\$20$. As such, there can be at most 3 days in that week at the end of a month.

Refining,

> Note that on the 3 days near the end of the month, he needs to spend at least $\$26+\$27+\$28=\$81>\$72$. As such, there can be at most 2 days in that week at the end of a month.

**Cases:**

> If there is one day in the week at the end of the month, then $72=x+1+2+3+4+5+6$, where $x$ is the amount spent at the end of the month. Here, $x>31$, so this is impossible.
>  If there are two days in the week at the end of the month, then $72=(x-1)+x+1+2+3+4+5$, where $x$ is the amount spent at the end of the month. This reduces to $72=2x+14$ or $x=29$. Hence, we can conclude that the month is a $29$-day month (found this mistake, credit to [Nizar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/227505/nizar)'s answer).

Answer (score 0):

Note that, as the case explained, this cant be happen unless you are in a leap where february has $29$   days, so the man spend  $28$ in $28$th of February, then $29$, then  $1,2,3,4,5$. Adding this you get that the man spends  $72$ $ .

Indeed as you said in your post, it is imposible for $7$ consecutive integers  between  $1$ and  $31$  to have sum  $72$. Moreover, if you take in consideration the end of each month with beginning of the following month, you will notice that this can happen just in the case of leap year  in the month of February .